# Removing partial git history

Tags: git, version-control

For example, I have a repo with 6 commits, from the oldest to newest, `1EE21B`, `4E5963`, `46EFEE`, `966437`, `410673`, `134023`. How do I remove commits from `4E5963` to `966437`, to make it look like `410673` comes directly after `1EE21B`? (`1EE21B` <- `410673` <- `134023`)

Comment: Do you wish to remove the changes from the commits or just make the history appear as though there are only two?

Comment: Just to make it appear as though there are only three commits, like the edits in the latest one is made directly after the first commit. Edit: I changed the example to 6 commits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use git rebase to squash commits into one. So you will have to do:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

You will then see in the vim editor something like:

```
pick 1EE21B a commit message 
pick 4E5963 a commit message
pick 966437 a commit message
pick 410673 a commit message
pick 134023 a commit message
```

You can mark commits as squashed which will meld them into the previous commit. To squash the commits into the first one you will need to change it to:

```
pick 1EE21B a commit message 
squash 4E5963 a commit message
squash 966437 a commit message
pick 410673 a commit message
pick 134023 a commit message
```

After saving in the vim editor you will then need to commit and `git push -f`. Here is a full [tutorial](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html) on how to do it.

EDIT: Be sure you have achieved your desired effect by checking the git log before pushing with force.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about squash. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, of course! Wasn't able to accept your answer back then because I was clicking "accept" too soon. Thank you!